# Como salvar um pdf do relatório estatístico gerado com pacote ExpDes.pt?

Tags: r, pdf, relatório, anova

o código abaixo gera um relatório no console do R o qual eu quero exportar em um pdf, no entanto não estou conseguindo, agradeço a ajuda.

```
library(ExpDes.pt)

anova1 <- fat2.dbc(dados$fator1, dados$fator2, dados$bloco, dados$var1, quali = c(FALSE, TRUE), mcomp = "tukey", fac.names = c("fator1", "fator2"), sigT = 0.05, sigF = 0.05)
```

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma é com o pacote `rmarkdown`. Veja também [R Markdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/).

Grave um **ficheiro de texto** `so_pt.Rmd` (ou com outro nome, mantenha a extensão) com o seguinte conteúdo.

````
---
title: "so_pt"
author: "Rui Barradas"
date: "28/01/2021"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

Isto é um documento R Markdown. Markdown é uma sintaxe de formatação simples para HTML, PDF e documentos MS Word. Veja R Markdown <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com> para mais detalhes.

Este documento serve para responder a uma pergunta do StackOverflow em Português.  

No código abaixo, substituir a instrução `fat2.dbc` pela instrução da pergunta.  

```{r}
library(ExpDes.pt)

data(ex5)
anova1 <- with(ex5,
               fat2.dbc(trat, genero, bloco, sabor, quali = c(TRUE, TRUE),
                        mcomp="lsd", fac.names=c("Amostras", "Genero"),
                        sigT = 0.05, sigF = 0.05)
)
```

A variável `anova1` tem a seguinte estrutura.  

```{r}
str(anova1)
```

Os dois `data.frame` podem ser vistos assim:

```{r results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

print(
  xtable(anova1$medias.fator1), 
  floating = FALSE, 
  include.rownames = FALSE,
  comment = FALSE
)


print(
  xtable(anova1$medias.fator2), 
  floating = FALSE, 
  include.rownames = FALSE,
  comment = FALSE
)

```
````